# Laravel relationships to the same table

Tags: relationship, laravel-8, has-many

I am a bit confused with Laravel relationships and need some help.

I have a table called: coffees
In the table I have a boolean field called: blend.

If it is a blend, it is made out of a few different coffees percentages.

For example, I have these coffees:

1 colombia

2 costa rica

3 brazil

I have a blend: Espresso which is made out of:

colombia 25%

costa rica 25%

brazil 50%

I created a pivot table called: blend_coffee with these fields:

blend_id

coffee_id

percent

I created this relationship in the Coffee model:

```
public function blend()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Coffee::class, 'blend_coffee', 'blend_id', 'coffee_id')->withPivot('percent');
    }
```

But now, I don't know how to display the coffees and their percentage for each blend.

If I try:

```
dd($coffee->blend)
```

I get the id of the blend

If I try:

```
foreach($coffee->blend as $blend)
```

I get the error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

I hope you can see my confusion and help.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do `$this->hasMany(...)` but this function only only accepts 3 arguments and you're passing 4. You should use `hasManyThrough` instead

Comment: Thank you, but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved my issue:

I have the coffees table.

I have a pivot table called: blend_coffee with fields:

blend_id, coffee_id, percent

And in the Coffee model I have these relationships:

```
public function blendCoffees()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Coffee::class, 'blend_coffee', 'blend_id', 'coffee_id')->withPivot('percent');
}
```

All is good in my kingdom. :)